# StoredProcedure em SQL-Server passando por parâmetro uma Lista C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, table, procedure, tsql

Gostaria de passar uma lista de parâmetros para uma procedure, como fazer esse processo?

Realizei umas pesquisas e achei que é possível criar um TYPE de TABLE e usar ela nos parâmetros da procedure, mas não consegui usar, segue exemplo.

```
CREATE TYPE TABLE_EXEC_PROCEDURE_MASSIVE_EXCHANGE_RELEASE_IMPORTED_FILE AS TABLE
(
    ID_MASSIVE_EXCHANGE UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    ID_IMPORTED_FILE_MASSIVE_EXCHANGE UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    POSICAO INT NOT NULL,
    USUARIO_EMAIL VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    USUARIO_NOME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    JUSTIFICATIVA VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

    CREATE PROCEDURE SP_EXEC_MASSIVE_EXCHANGE_RELEASE_IMPORTED_FILE
    @TABLE TABLE_EXEC_PROCEDURE_MASSIVE_EXCHANGE_RELEASE_IMPORTED_FILE READONLY AS
    BEGIN

    END
```

Alguém teria algum exemplo?

Comment: Bom dia, por que você não manda os dados em uma string e na procedure você joga os dados para uma temporária... Onde trabalho fazemos dessa forma e funciona.